# Trouble Pinning Async Fn Object Using Tokio

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I seem unable to use [pnet's datalink library](https://docs.rs/pnet/0.27.2/pnet/index.html) in any asynchronous way. The trouble appears to relate to pinning. This snippet adapted from pnet's main example:

```
async fn ethernet_channel(i: NetworkInterface) {
    // Create Ethernet channel:
    let (mut tx, mut rx) = match datalink::channel(&i, Default::default()) {
        Ok(Ethernet(tx, rx)) => (tx, rx),
        _ => panic!("Error creating channel")
    };

    loop { // handle inbound Ethernet packets forever
        tokio::select! {
            Ok(packet) = rx.next() => {}
            // TODO: include some arm like an mpsc oneshot to break out, like Tokio's examples
        }
    }
}
```

Leads to compiler error: `ror[E0599]: no method named 'poll' found for struct 'Pin<&mut std::result::Result<&[u8], std::io::Error>>' in the current scope`

The Tokio tutorial [covers this exact scenario](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/select#resuming-an-async-operation) and includes this remark: "to .await a reference, the value being referenced must be pinned or implement Unpin."

Combined with knowing the return value of the `rx.next()` function is the `Result<&[u8], Error>` mentioned in the error, I gather the packet byte array is the culprit "value being referenced" that must be pinned. I've tried many combinations of tokio::pin!(), including what makes the most sense to me based on Tokio's same example, to no avail:

```
#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    for interface in datalink::interfaces() {
        let operation = ethernet_channel(interface);
        tokio::pin!(operation);
        tokio::select! {
            _ = &mut operation => {}
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried tokio::pin!() within my "ethernet_channel()" function, before and after datalink::channel(), on both the NetworkInterface and rx. I always end up with the same error as above. Any guidance appreciated, pulling my hair out.

Comment: The `pnet` library doesn't seem to support async to begin with? And in that case, you're going to have a *really hard* time trying to use it in that way, if it's even possible at all.